# В чем ошибка данного запроса MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть БД, в котрой несколько таблиц: `groups (id, name)`, `students (id, name, surname, gr_id)`, `marks (id, st_id, d_id, t_id, mark)`.

Необходимо подсчитать количество групп, которым выставлены оценки. Ругается по поводу синтаксиса возле `FROM marks) AS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT groups.id) 
FROM groups JOIN students JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT st_id FROM marks) AS der_table 
ON (groups.id = students.gr_id AND students.id = der_table.st_id);
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, хочу разобраться в этом вопросе.

Comment: ON должен быть после каждого JOIN а не в скобках в конце......`JOIN students ON groups.id = students.gr_id JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT st_id FROM marks) AS der_table 
ON students.id = der_table.st_id`  это как минимум

Comment: Почему вы не хотите привести код и текст ошибки?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,спасибо Вам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы неправильно написали sql-запрос. [Соединение](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html) нескольких таблиц происходит по принципу:

```
table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
          JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id /* и т.д. */
```

Таким образом, ваш запрос будет выглядеть как:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT groups.id) 
FROM groups JOIN students ON groups.id = students.gr_id
     JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT st_id FROM marks) AS der_table ON students.id = der_table.st_id
```

Либо можете избавиться от второго соединения таблиц и сделать подзапрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT groups.id) 
FROM groups JOIN students ON groups.id = students.gr_id
WHERE students.id IN (SELECT st_id FROM marks)
```

Comment: Скажите , а **IN** в данном случае как бы указывает,что id из таблици стулнтов - тож, что и st_id из marks? И Ві говорите, что благодаря подзапросу  сам запрос будет быстрее, а ведь все три таблици все равно будут связаны?????

Comment: @MuscledBoy нет, с подзапросом будет работать медленней, но если данных немного, то разницы почти не увидите. Насчет `in`, чтобы не вдаваться в подробности, лучше почитайте тут - http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_predicate_in.html

Comment: @Demis, спасибо за ответ,спасибо за ссылку и за понятное объяснение